# find a specific groupId from a maven pom.xml using xmstarlet

Tags: xmlstarlet

I'm trying to find a specific groupId and artifactId from a Maven POM.XML using xmlstarlet without success.
This is the command that I'm using:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N pom=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t \
     -m "/pom:project/pom:dependencyManagement/pom:dependencies/pom:dependency[.//pom:groupId=com.mygroup.xxx]" \ 
     -v '.' pom.xml
```

any Help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thank to npostavs, for other people who have the same question, It is also possible to combine more expressions and filter the result based on more elements:

```
  xmlstarlet sel -N pom=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m "/pom:project/pom:dependencyManagement/pom:dependencies/dependency[.//pom:groupId='com.mygroup.xxx'][.//pom:artifactId='myartifact-xxx']" -v '.' pom.xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `pom:groupId=com.mygroup.xxx`

You need quotes around string literals: `pom:groupId='com.mygroup.xxx'`, otherwise it looks for XML elements named `com.mygroup.xxx`.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate for this.